# FHT x MHT bibb with screw mounts

Tags: hose, spigot

I am running a hose under a deck which has a wooden "fence" covering the "crawl space". I'd like to have a spigot on the side of the deck where the hose come out. Do they make something like this that I can screw a hose in the back/inlet and screwn the bib into the fence? All of the bibs I've found with screw mounts like this do not have FHT on the inlet, and all of the bibs I've found with FHT on the inlet do not have a mounting flange/holes. Any recommendations?

[image]

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, you plan to use a length of garden hose as the 'extension' under the deck to reach from the house over to the new spigot? If so I'd make very sure that the hose you use is rated to handle continuous water-main pressure for an indefinite period of time without springing a leak.

Comment: Also, be very vigilant about shutting off the water in the fall and draining the hose before you hit freezing temps (if your climate gets freezing temps).

Comment: @brhans Interesting - I didn't realize hoses had "continuous pressure" ratings. I'll check it out. 
FreeMan - yep, just ordered a coupler so I can connect an air compressor to the hose to blow it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a "pipe thread-to-hose thread" adapter:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to pass through pipe threads in the adapter part of the world if you want this done with hose.

I do see PEX to FGHT (female garden hose thread) fittings, so if you are coming from a hose bibb and going into this you could use PEX rather than hose, with a FGHT fitting at the one end and MPT (male pipe thread) or FPT (female pipe thread) fitting at the other end.